# sh: 1: cucumber.js: not found

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumber, nvm

Trying to use this tutorial here:

https://github.com/lykmapipo/nodejs-cucumber-sample

The output to `nvm current` is: `v10.12.0`.

The output to `npm --version` is: `6.4.1`>

I get the error below once I invoke `npm test`:

```
> nodejs-cucumber-sample@0.0.1 test /home/gnuc/code/nodejs-cucumber-sample
> cucumber.js

sh: 1: cucumber.js: not found
```

I am not sure as to why this is the case. The `$PATH` includes `/home/gnuc/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin`. And I have already used `npm install cucumber -g` and `npm install cucumber`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure that your package.json file includes this: `"test": "cucumber-js"`

So that it looks something like this:

```
{
      "name": "hellocucumber",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": **"cucumber-js"**
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "cucumber": "^5.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to actually call the npm package/library.  I have the following defined in my package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js"
 },
```

you can also add some ---tags in this call.

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @RegressionTestSuite"
 },
```

this will run any feature files that have @RegressionTestSuite at the top

Also, I have an output/results file created with a time stamp.

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @RegressionTestSuite --format json:./results/log_new_`date +%Y-%m-%m__%H-%M`.json""
 },
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

> node ./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js

This command is working fine.
And you got sh:1: cucumber.js: not found error means first things please look out the path of cucumber.js